# Scanning a Foreign Network for Active Hosts using Nmap or Hping3

Tags: nmap

I Have a Router setup at my home. I Just have a private IP. I wanted to scan for active hosts on my network. When I do it locally, I use, **Nmap**,

```
nmap -sn -v x.x.x.*
```

So, is their any way to do it externally ?

**P.S** I have a port 80 Forwarded.

Comment: You could setup a small server (like a raspberry pi) on your local network, portforward the SSH port, and install nmap on it. If you aren't home, you can then SSH into the pi and execute a scan from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.2.0/24
```

If you are indeed thinking of a NAT'ed 'foreign network', then no, you can't, other than portscanning the internet faced side of the NAT for open ports.

Comment: But I m not connected to my network. I just have IP address

Answer (score 1):

I think the Answer is No.

Assuming the router has no port forwards set from Private Network to outside, Its not possible to scan a Private Network ([NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)) from outside the Private Network(From the Internet).

Lets say your NAT has IP address like `192.168.0.xxx`.
Now these exact IPs will be located in many other NAT's.

If you scan something like `192.168.0.10` you either end with `Host not found` or will probably scan someone one else who is reachable from the private network you are currently on.

**EDIT:** If you really want to do it, you can setup [Port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)  for the hosts in Private network and then scan the router IP for open ports.

**UPADTE:** After setting up Port Forwarding,the command will be `nmap -sn -v RouterIP` . But lets say you mapped `HostIP:8080` to `RouterIP:9090`. You will get port `RouterIP:9090` open. So you require to know the Mapping between RouterIP and hosts ip

Comment: what if, I get an Open Port, which is forwarded ?

Comment: Then the `Host IP:port` which got mapped to  the  `RouterIP:Port` is open.

Comment: then, what is the command for scanning it ?

Comment: @M.S.P The command will be `nmap -sn -v RouterIP` . But lets say you mapped HostIP:8080 to RouterIP:9090. You will get port 9090 open. So you require to know the Mapping between RouterIP and hosts ip

Comment: Kindly, add that to your answer. Ill mark it correct.

Comment: @M.S.P Just did that :)